# Send file based on user-Agent

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'am trying to write a python socket server which serves compressed (gzip) content if the user agent is a desktop. If the user agent is a mobile phone then it serves the content without compression. 
Any idea how to do it. 
Thank  You

Comment: The user agent is sent, in most case optionally, with some protocols like HTTP. It is not available in pure TCP sockets.

Comment: As @KlausD. indicated, this is dependent on the protocol being used for the agent to talk to your server.  **user agent** is a term mostly used for the http protocol.  if you are implementing your own protocol, then you need to include some way in that protocol for the agent to identify itself as desktop or mobile.  if you're implementing an http protocol server, I recommend looking at one of the http server libraries such as `BaseHTTPServer` or `SimpleHTTPServer`.

Comment: Assuming capabilities of the client based on the user agent is a bad idea. The client says within the `Accept-Encoding` header if compression is supported and which  methods (gzip, deflate, br...) are supported. Please use only this to decide if you compress the content and how.